# Custom Search Center URL does not work on mobile

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile

In company we use custom SharePoint Search URL defined in site Search Settings.
After hitting enter on desktop views redirection works fine.
In mobile devices and mobile SharePoint app it does not work and native SPO search pops-out.

What can be a reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint app doesn't use your site's custom search settings. That's why it doesn't work on mobile. Unfortunately, you can’t change this in the app.